# Systemctl restart service triggering another command

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I created systemd service, which runs a script that auto-generates some configuration files if these don't exist, and loads the services depending on them, or loads the services with the existing ones.

I would like to provide some extra functionality, allowing the user to clean previous configurations using the same systemctl service.

I thought in **`ExecReload`**, thinking that it would be called when the user types **`systemctl restart service_name`**, but then I discovered that it is not doing what I thought.

Is there a way to do i?
I was checking here and in [Freedesktop Systemd doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), but I could not find the way

Comment: The trouble is that you're limited to [`systemctl`'s interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html), which means verbs like `start`, `stop`, or `reload`, which you probably don't want to overload. Are you open to using something besides `systemctl` as the interface to this?

Comment: yes, thank you: finally I created a script in /sbin to clean, re-build the configuration and reload the service

Comment: The command in `ExecReload=` is executed when you run `systemctl reload`, not `restart` (which does `srop` followed by `start`.) I guess it's not completely clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, would you care to give more details, like a more detailed description of what config files you want to generate and which services you want to start/restart/reload from your custom service? That would help us give you a better suggestion on how to accomplish what you're trying to do... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you're limited to systemctl's interface, which means verbs like `start`, `stop`, or `reload`, which you probably don't want to overload. My suggestion would be to use a separate interface altogether, such as a `kill -USR1` signal handler or a separate script that you can invoke.